# Prestashop Webservice - Outuput specific details

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

This is the code I have right now:

```
public static function listProducts() {

    require_once('inc/config/config.php');

    try {
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
        $opt = array('resource' => 'products', 'display' => 'full');
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);
        $resources = $xml->products->children();
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {
        $trace = $e->getTrace();
        if($trace[0]['args'][0] = 404) echo "BAD ID";
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] = 401) echo "BAD AUTH KEY";
        else echo 'OTHER ERROR';
    }

    $output = json_encode($resources, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    echo $output;
}
```

How can I output specific resources/details about my products?
Right now this outputs everything.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$resources` to see what's inside?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use webservices documentation for 1.5 version, in 1.6 lack of details.

```
$opt = array(
    'resource'          =>'customers',
    'display'           => '[birthday]',
    'filter[firstname]' => '[John]',
    'filter[lastname]'  => '[DOE]'
);
```

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+Use#Chapter8-AdvancedUse-SortingFilters